# Fatal exception and error opening trace file

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm working on an Music Player, based on Apollo, an app built for Cyanogenmod. Upon loading and launching the app onto a emulator, the following appeared in the logcat view

```
    05-26 08:58:16.539: E/Trace(1108): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-26 08:58:16.687: W/dalvikvm(1108): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/echolabs/echo/ui/activities/BaseActivity; (146)
05-26 08:58:16.697: W/dalvikvm(1108): Link of class 'Lcom/echolabs/echo/ui/activities/BaseActivity;' failed
05-26 08:58:16.697: W/dalvikvm(1108): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/echolabs/echo/ui/activities/HomeActivity; (421)
05-26 08:58:16.697: W/dalvikvm(1108): Link of class 'Lcom/echolabs/echo/ui/activities/HomeActivity;' failed
05-26 08:58:16.697: D/AndroidRuntime(1108): Shutting down VM
05-26 08:58:16.717: W/dalvikvm(1108): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.echolabs.echo/com.echolabs.echo.ui.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.echolabs.echo.ui.activities.HomeActivity" on path: /data/app/com.echolabs.echo-1.apk
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.echolabs.echo.ui.activities.HomeActivity" on path: /data/app/com.echolabs.echo-1.apk
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-26 08:58:16.729: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 11 more
```

I honestly have **Absolutely NO** idea where these problems are coming from. If anyone out there can find the root of the problem, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your R.java generated file.

Goto `Project` --> `Clean` in your eclipse.

and wait for your project to rebuild.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however a new logcat was generated with the same + newer errors, I will update it accordingly.

Comment: While cleaning a project isn't a bad idea, this is a bit random a suggestion to be posted as an Answer.  Can you explain why you believed the issue was with R.java?

Comment: It could be that or another generated file, IEchoService.java, those are the only files known to me that have errors outside of the class files found in the packages.

Comment: In addition, there are no flags in the problems log that have any of those class names listed.